# Docker image generating error for /usr/bin/java

Tags: linux, docker

I am trying to run this docker image, but not sure why I am getting this error:

```
/usr/bin/time: cannot run /usr/bin/java: No such file or directory
Command exited with non-zero status 127
```

Can someone please help me debug this error?

My docker file:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jre
LABEL maintainer="APN <xxx@xxx.edu>"

LABEL org.label-schema.schema-version="1.0"
# LABEL org.label-schema.build-date=$BUILD_DATE
LABEL org.label-schema.name="apn/addreadgroups"
LABEL org.label-schema.description="Image for adding read groups in .bam"

ENV PICARD_VERSION 2.20.8

WORKDIR /tmp

RUN apt-get update -y \
  && apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y \
       make \
       gcc \
       g++ \
       libz-dev \
       libbz2-dev \
       liblzma-dev \
       ncurses-dev \
       bc \
       libnss-sss \
       time \
  && cd /tmp \
  && wget -q -O /usr/bin/picard.jar https://github.com/broadinstitute/picard/releases/download/${PICARD_VERSION}/picard.jar \
  && ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/Chicago /etc/localtime \
  && echo "America/Chicago" > /etc/timezone \
  && dpkg-reconfigure --frontend noninteractive tzdata \
  && apt-get clean all \
  && rm -rfv /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/* 

# This makes the image crazy large -- will find a workaround
# COPY human_g1k_v37_decoy* /usr/local/

COPY ./entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/
ENV PICARD /usr/bin/picard.jar

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh"]
# CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

and the entrypoint.sh:

```
JAVAOPTS="-Xms2g -Xmx${MEM}g -XX:+UseSerialGC -Dpicard.useLegacyParser=false"

CUR_STEP="AddOrReplaceReadGroups"
/usr/bin/java ${JAVAOPTS} -jar "${PICARD}" \
  "${CUR_STEP}" \
    I="${INBAM}" \
    O=${BAMFILE} \
    RGID=${FLOWCELL} \
    RGLB=${LIBRARY} \
    RGPL=${PLATFORM} \
    RGPU=${FLOWCELL} \
    RGSM=${SM}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exit status `127` means no command found.

This is due to the `java` command in `openjdk:8-jre` not located in `/usr/bin/java`, see next:

```
$ docker run -it openjdk:8-jre which java
/usr/local/openjdk-8/bin/java
```